# How do I trigger events using Meteor server side events

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am using Meteor, which uses Mongodb as its database. I have code that inserts several documents into a collection when users fill out a form. When these documents are inserted, I would like to fire some JavaScript code within the server side directories that sorts through the collection in question for documents with matching fields as the documents just inserted.

My problem is that I do not know how to fire code on the server when the new documents arrive. Would it make sense to `Meteor.call` a Meteor.method at the end of the code involved with inserting, with the Meteor.method called preforming the sorting code I need?

**Edit:**

As you can see, in the below code I'm not calling any Meteor methods as none exist yet. The vast majority of this code is simply lead up for the `insert({})` at the end of the page, so I think it can be safely ignored. The only server side code I have is to declare the possibleGames mongo collection.

I am not sure what you mean by call a plain JavaScript function, my problem is getting any code firing at all.

```
possibleGames = new Mongo.Collection("possibleGames");

Template.meet_form.events({
"submit .meet_form": function(event, template){
event.preventDefault();

var user = Meteor.userId();
var where = event.target.where.value;

var checkedGames = [];
function gameCheck (game) {
  if (game.checked === true){
    checkedGames.push(game.value);
  };
};

var checkedDays = [];
function dayCheck (day) {
  if (day.checked === true){
    checkedDays.push(day.value);
  };
};

console.log(event.target.where.value)

gameCheck(event.target.dnd);
gameCheck(event.target.savageWorlds);
gameCheck(event.target.shadowRun);
console.log(checkedGames);

dayCheck(event.target.monday);
dayCheck(event.target.tuesday);
dayCheck(event.target.wednesday);
dayCheck(event.target.thursday);
dayCheck(event.target.friday);
dayCheck(event.target.saturday);
dayCheck(event.target.sunday);
console.log(checkedDays);

var whereWhat = [];
for (i = 0; i < checkedGames.length; i++) {
  var prepareWhereWhat = where.concat(checkedGames[i]);
  whereWhat.push(prepareWhereWhat);
};
console.log(whereWhat);

var whereWhatWhen = [];
for (a = 0; a < whereWhat.length; a++) {
  var prepareWWW1 = whereWhat[a];
  for (b = 0; b < checkedDays.length; b++) {
    var prepareWWW2 = prepareWWW1.concat(checkedDays[b]);
    whereWhatWhen.push(prepareWWW2);
  };
};
console.log(whereWhatWhen);


for (i = 0; i < whereWhatWhen.length; i++) {
  possibleGames.insert({
    game: whereWhatWhen[i],
    user: user,
    created_on: new Date().getTime()
    })
}

}
});
```

Comment: What kind of code do you want to execute on the server?

Comment: An `insert` from the client results in a `Meteor.method` call, just not the one that you triggered. For security, you should either employ `allow/deny` rules on the server or prevents the client from directly mutating data via insert/update and use explicit methods instead. Make sure that you validate the input from the client side. You can perform the desired queries in the method body on the server, or use something like the `collection-hooks` package or an `event-emitter` to execute something when the collection changes/something happens.

Comment: I have not puzzled it out entirely yet, but I think a collection.find(), using the document's entries that just arrived as the selector, then do something with the results of the collection.find().

I have a funny feeling that the answer is blindingly obvious and a staple of all meteor code, and everyone just assumes that I know about this code and have run into some abnormal problems when using it. I just don't know about the code.

Comment: As I mentioned, you *are* calling methods on the server (implicitly when `insert`ing), just not a method that you wrote yourself. I can suggest that you think of a method call as your client trying to tell you server something about something concrete that had just happened. Figure out what the appropriate _thing_ is and then create a method for it with the relevant logic. Then you will be able to get the data that you want from the DB (as it will run on the server). Take your time, read the docs and [the Meteor manual](https://manual.meteor.com).

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'll look into this.

Comment: whoops, I meant [The Meteor Guide](http://guide.meteor.com/). :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do a meteor.call on the server because you're already on the server. 
Just call a plain javascript function.

If what you want to call from your first Meteor.method is already in another Meteor.method, then refactor that function to extract out the common bit.

Some code would also help if this is still confusing.

Comment: I think this section of the meteor guide might help you?http://guide.meteor.com/methods.html#defining-and-calling
What you're doing there is optimistic update, updating minimongo and letting meteor do the call in the background. I'd recommend doing a Meteor.Call explicitly first to see how the plumbing works.